# Can one Given When Then story drive > 1 JBhave Steps?

Tags: bdd, jbehave

I've created a .story file with a Given When Then (GWT).

Contact_List.story
Scenario: Discover Contact
Given I've a contact list of friends
When one of them is online
Then that friend is displayed in a list

I'd like to have two levels of testing (a bunch of fast service layer tests, and a few UI tests).  So I created the following using the exact same GWT language:

ServiceSteps.java

```
@Given("I've a contact list of friends")
...
```

UISteps.java

```
@Given("I've a contact list of friends")
....
```

And Configured JBehave to use both of them:
RunBDDTests.java

```
...
@Override
public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {       
    // varargs, can have more that one steps classes
    return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), new ServiceSteps(), new UISteps());
}
...
```

But, when running this in JUNit, each time I run the tests, it's random as to which Steps class it selects.

How to have it run both steps each time so that one .story file drives > 1 steps class?

Answer (score 2):

This is organized by the Configuration.  In JBehave parlance, the Configuration is the class that tells the JBehave framework how to associate *.stories with *Steps.java.  In the questioniers example, this is RunBDDTests.java.  One option that will associate two steps with a single GWT scenario is to create two Configurations, one for the Service steps and one for the UI steps:

```
ServiceConfiguration.java

public class ServiceConfiguration extends JUnitStories
{
 @Override
 public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {       

    return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), new ServiceSteps()); // <- note steps class
 }

@Override
protected List<String> storyPaths() {

    return new StoryFinder().findPaths(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass()), "**/Contact_List.story", "");  //<- note story file name
}
}
```

UIConfiguration.java

```
public class UIConfiguration extends JUnitStories
{
    @Override
    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {              
      return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), new UISteps()); // <- note steps class
    }

@Override
protected List<String> storyPaths() {       
  return new StoryFinder().findPaths(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass()), "**/Contact_List.story", "");  //<- note story file name
}
}
```

The above two configurations will run two different step files against one .story.

Comment: What if I have, say, 10 different step pools, how do I organize that? Is creating a separate JUnitStories class for each step-pool necessary, or is there a way to provide some nicer mapping?

Comment: 10 different JUnit test cases can handle that. You may find another way too. I'm not sure if you're exaggerating to 10 for effect. Requiring 10 different pools seems like something is wrong and that your feature file is TOO generic. Having one feature file drive different steps is typically used to drive the same feature but at different levels of the test automation pyramid (http://agilenoir.biz/series/agile-thoughts/). There is typically only 2-3 levels a "macro" test needs to bridge. Another reason is if there are 10 diff teams involved with one feature and they want 2 test their piece.

Comment: Btw, when I said "JUnit Test cases" I meant JUnitStories."

Comment: That's real case, I have about 10 small services that my team is testing and I have to migrate to JBehave. I have sets of .story files organized in folders (one folder per service), and I totally don't want different services to use same step-pools.

Comment: I see. Good news is that you can do this in the case you and the team can't reword the language in the feature files so their steps declarations (given when then...) don't overlap. The JUnitStory code is simple enough (once you get the configuration the way you want it) it's not hard to maintain. Especially if you do some subclassing or composition. BDD practitioners would rather you work as a group and change the feature files in a way the language doesn't "unnaturally" overlap so you can have global (ideally) step definitions. But I get the sense your situation lacks flexibility.

Comment: One of the ideas of having global definitions is to force the conflict of devs and business to work together as a team so the boundary between Dev and business is diminished. Not all organizations are ready for that but it's good for you to know why BDD frameworks are putting you through this hassle. Your organization (or team) may not be well designed for BDD. If you can't redesign those relationships, you'll get the work done as we've described, and you'll get experience working with BDD and test automation. That'll be valuable experience. And the business will get gets automation.

Comment: I'm trying to use the solution from the answer, but only getting Failed to run stories as embeddables: MyStories: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@beaec53 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@448fafc1[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 2]. Any Ideas why?

Comment: @Alissa I'm not familiar with that.  I see via google number of posts about Maven and JBehave and some are posting solutions. I searched for "Failed to run stories as embeddables".  I also see something about TestNG (a tester runner and assertion library like JUnit) and others about trying to execute tests in parallel when searching "java.util.concurrent.rejectedexecutionexception jbehave".

Comment: Does this happen only when using your Configuration? Also a mailing list here: http://jbehave.org/mailing-lists.html. Sorry I've no better advice about that problem. Think about how your launching the test (Maven of via a test runner). That snippet you sent me isn't helping much. Perhaps email the whole stack trace to me at LancerKind@gmail.com and explain your runtime environment (what version of Java) and how your launching your tests (Maven, JUnit runner, TestNG, ...) I'd send it off to the JBehave list too as someone whose has had that problem will have the answer. :-)

Comment: I have almost same config as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35778847/error-when-trying-to-run-jbehave-with-maven-3-rejectedexecutionexception except that log4j is a project-level dependency and no <scope> tag. Maybe you could provide answer there?

Comment: It works with a runner (more or less as described in http://jbehave.org/reference/latest/running-stories.html). But not with maven. And in runner, I need to put a separate method for each JUnitStories class.

Comment: Here are some suggestions for running with Maven: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35778847/error-when-trying-to-run-jbehave-with-maven-3-rejectedexecutionexception

Comment: yep, that's what I'm trying to use. And it doesn't work (FutureTask@... rejected from ThreadPoolExacutor@...)