# Elegant way of organizing multiple step pools for JBehave

Tags: java, jbehave

I'm writing tests for several small services, and I don't want all services to share same steps-pool.

I started with using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16594434/1395875), but a bit DRYed (I have an abstract class with all methods needed and child classes each defining a class with steps and a path pattern for story-files). A typical child class would look like this:

```
class SomeServiceStories extends AbstractStories{
    SomeServiceStories(){
        super (new SomeServiceSteps(), "**/someservice/**/*.story")
    }
}
```

But I don't like that I have to have about 10 of these almost empty classes. What I'm thinking of, is some Map of story path patterns to steps class (or instance of it).

So, is there a nice and elegant way to have such step-pools organized?

Comment: Would you welcome a discussion on how best to test "several small services?"  There are a lot of possibilities and I'm unsure that JBehave and multiple step pools is optimal. For example, are these services working with changing data or do you have control of the data? Another is, are these small services part of the same feature or are they for unrelated applications?  (If unrelated then treat as separate features with their own story file.

Comment: @LanceKind it probably is not optimal, but that's the way it is, and I have to have it like this. Services are mostly validation services an lookups (e.g. validate an email, lookup a customer, etc.). They are parts of a bigger service, but not exactly related. So, I'm OK with discussion because it might help someone in future, though it won't help me...